# How much memory is allocated for argv[]?

Tags: c++, linux, command-line-arguments

I know that the command line arguments are character arrays and that they are stored on the stack. But, I want to know actual memory allocation for of each argument. e.g. suppose I passed the directory name `"/tmp"` as a command line argument. This will be stored in `argv[1]`. But as I tested, it is allowed to change `argv[1]` to `"/tmp/log/"` (size increased) in the program. How is this possible ?

Comment: "I know that" followed by unsubstantiated speculation.

Comment: "But has I tested, it is allowed to change argv[1] to "/tmp/log/" (size increased) in program." Yes, the C standards allow you to modify the strings pointed to by `argv` ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 5.1.2.2.1, clause 2, last constraint), but "increasing their size" is probably UB. You should assume that there is exactly as much modifiable `char[]` as there is a zero-terminated string.

Comment: If you `argv[1] = "/tmp/log")`, you're not increasing the size of the string pointed to by `argv[1]`, you're replacing one pointer with another. I doubt that `strcat(argv[1], "/log")` would be as successful.

Comment: what about cin>>argv[1]. I mean I tested it. How does that work?

Comment: @techiek7 Is this a C or a C++ question?

Comment: @techiek7 That overwrites the string, so if the input is longer than the original argument, it will be UB.

Comment: I know that SO really loves to downvote people, but given that a platform was specified, and that that platform is open source, there is a verifiable answer to this question.

Comment: "But as I tested, it is allowed to change `argv[1]` to `"/tmp/log/"`" is a description of what you did.  Posting the _code_ is better evidence and makes for a better question and answer.  It also adds clarity

Comment: @MooingDuck, argument passing is controlled by the kernel on Linux. It has no other dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the total maximum size available to argument strings and the passed environment can be obtained with:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

from the command line or the syconf equivalent from C (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html for more information).
(On my Linux box, the limit is 2097152).

Your example happens to work because the arguments and the environment are realistically stored contiguously, so appending to a string will overwrite what comes after it (following arguments, or the environment).
And that's why it's a bad idea to try and expand the argv strings like that. If you want to modify them, either edit them or shrink them, but trying to expand them is a call for trouble.

Comment: This answers it very well. Additionally I tried to print 100 characters after starting address of argv[0][0].  Arguments and the environment are actually stored contiguously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, parameters are populated by [`create_elf_tables`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L294). For this specific platform at least, you are correct that the values are stored on the stack.

Linux only uses exactly as much memory as is necessary to store arguments and (initial) environment variables on the stack; if you try to use more than what is already there, you're overwriting something else (or crashing).

Answer (score 0):

The standard states that the argv can be modified since it is a special internal.

177 —  The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination, so it is allocated only what you need at the assignment or replacement.

Standard text:
http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html

Comment: Note you have referenced the _proposed_ C standard.